# Drupal: How to override Advanced Forum topic list for one specific forum term

Tags: drupal

I'm using Drupal 7, and have the Advanced Forum module installed.

However, I want to show some Ubercart products in one section of the forum, called the Marketplace to make them more visible, and since users will be able to add their own products.

However, obviously in this section I want to show the forum topic list differently, including the price and other such fields.

Is there an easy way that I'd be able to do this, perhaps using Views? I'm really at a loss for what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just create a new View with a page display that displays things like you want them and then set the URL for the view to be the URL that is currently being used for the forum listing you want to override, so that the links to it still work without any additional work.

Comment: How so? Simply that I tried creating a view for the path of the forum, but when going to that path, it does not display that view, but the default view from Advanced Forum instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should override the page template for one specific term by creating a new page like so:

```
page__forum_TERMID
```

To go more into details about what you need to show in this custom page, you may need to install the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel)  & [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) modules.

With Theme developer you will be able to inspect your Drupal output on various parts of the page in order to find out either which preprocess function or which template it originates from.

With Devel you will be able to output some of the variables you may need to act upon in order to generate your custom layout.

I would advise you to look at the implementation of the [Advanced Forum More Styles](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum_more_styles) in order to see how you could create your own Advanced Forum Style, which basically means a folder where you can store the various custom templates that will override the Advanced Forum templates.

Recently, I did something similar to what you're looking to achieve, I created a custom module to hold the various preprocess functions and that module contained a styles folder which was declared like so:

```
function YOURMODULENAME_ctools_plugin_directory($module, $plugin) {
  if ($module == 'advanced_forum') {
    return 'styles';
  }
}
```

If you look at the styles in the AF module, you will see that they only override a few templates, so you may have to find the template you're looking for in the base style such as the "Naked" style.